# Diesel engine fuel return pressure -- how high above the engine can the fuel tank be

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, fuel-tank

This is specifically regarding an inline six cylinder direct injection, external injectors, and injection pump.  Circa 1998.  Just a stock standard Diesel motor....  But in general also.

The bush camp I work at has 3 generators, the fuel tank is on a bit of a hill behind it, so the returning fuel has to be pumped up (by the FIP) maybe 6 feet.  So basically the return line had 2.5 or 3 psi back pressure the pump has to overcome.

It seams odd to me, never seen a fuel tank above or (much above) the motor.  Is this ok? What would the limit be?

Answer (score 1):

Not MVMR but why not have a small return tank level with the engine and then a separate pump to pump the fuel back to the big tank when close to full. Would only operate sporadically.

Comment: Why is this not MVM&R?